# Element disapears after detach() and appendTo()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using hQuery's draggable" & "droppable". When I drop an element I want to move it from its previous parent to its dropped parent.

But when I detach and append it, it disappears! Why?

If I do a `console.log` on the dragged element, I can see that it has changed parents.

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/6/

**JS**

```
//Make elements Draggable
$('.elementsDiv').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
  });

  $('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
    accept: '.elementsDiv',
    drop: function(event, ui) {

  //Get dragged Element (checked)
  draggedElement = $(ui.draggable);

  //Get dropZone where element is dropped (checked)
  dropZone = $(event.target);

  //Remove element from DOM (prev parent)
  $(draggedElement).detach();

  //Append element to DOM (new parent)
  $(draggedElement).appendTo(dropZone);
  },
});
```

**UPDATED FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/13/

This is to demonstrate that the dropped element us not attched to dropZone, but only to the document...

Comment: its not actually diappearing... there is prob with  setting its `top` position value... kindly check updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/0apuqnxd/7/

Comment: @RRR Interesting. How come, and how can i solve it? I need to reset the position, i guess... and then get the dropped position and append it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that coordinate is wrong.

When drop a item, it is placed on upper coordinate better than dropped coordinate.

```
$('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
  accept: '.elementsDiv',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log(event);
    console.log(ui.offset.top);
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
       // Move draggable into droppable
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    console.log(offset);
    var relX = event.pageX - offset.left;
    var relY = event.pageY - offset.top;
    draggable.css({"left": ui.offset.left, "top": ui.offset.top, "position": "absolute"}).appendTo(droppable);
  },
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChaHyukIm/0apuqnxd/12/

Comment: But what you have done is only changed the css for the element, you havent moved it to another "parent" ?

Comment: Where do you use relX and relY?

Comment: oh, i forgot remove relX, relY. Don't use.

Comment: The element hasn't moved into it's droped parent..because it don't moves with it's parent when DOM is changed?!

Comment: But i guess you answeared my question about position. Thank you! I've started a new quertion for you to solve here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300587/jquery-detach-and-append-to-new-parent