# Jquery `detach()` and `append` to new parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a dynamic webpage where i use Jquery "draggable" & "droppable".
I'm trying to move one element from one "parent" to another.

When i do "console.log" i can see that the element has a new parent.
But When i later on add more HTML content to the DOM, the element won't move with it's new parent. It's stuck to the "document" offset position.
How can i solve this?

**FIDDLE**
https://jsfiddle.net/0apuqnxd/13/

**JS**

```
      //Make elements Draggable
  $('.elementsDiv').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
  });
  var flakUpId = $('#1').attr('id');

  $('#btnAddDropZone').on('click', function() {
    flakUpId++;
    var flakUp = "<div class='flakUp'>DropZone " + flakUpId + " </div>";
    $('#dropZones').prepend(flakUp);
  })

  $('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
    accept: '.elementsDiv',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var droppable = $(this);
      var draggable = ui.draggable;

      //Detach element from DOM
      draggable.detach();

      //Append element to droped position and into new parent?
      draggable.css({
        "left": ui.offset.left,
        "top": ui.offset.top,
        "position": "absolute"
      }).appendTo(droppable);
    },
  });
```

Comment: when you append it to another element, you remove it from its current parent's tree

Comment: @VictorFerreira ok, great! But why will the dropped element not move with it's parent when the parent is moved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
//Make elements Draggable
$('.elementsDiv').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
});
var flakUpId = $('#1').attr('id');

$('#btnAddDropZone').on('click', function() {
  flakUpId++;
  var flakUp = "<div class='flakUp'>DropZone " + flakUpId + " </div>";
  $('#dropZones').prepend(flakUp);

  registDroppable();

  $(".flakUp .elementsDiv").each(function(e) {
    $(this).css({"top": $(this).offset().top+$(".flakUp").height()});
  });
})

function registDroppable() {
    $('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
    accept: '.elementsDiv',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var droppable = $(this);
      var draggable = ui.draggable;
      // Move draggable into droppable

      draggable.css({
        "left": ui.offset.left,
        "top": ui.offset.top,
        "position": "absolute"
      }).appendTo(droppable);
    },
  });
}
registDroppable();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ChaHyukIm/0apuqnxd/15/

Comment: Well it works with my example, but not in my real code. Because i have the dropzones into another div, so the position will glide some 50px. It would be great if the dropped element will be children of the dropzone and always follow them..

Answer (score 0):

I just changed three things and it seems working:

1) added ID and class when you add new Div:
  a)id="12" - Hardcoded to Test you can change later
  b) class="ui-droppable" added

```
$('#btnAddDropZone').on('click', function() {
  flakUpId++;
  var flakUp = "<div id='12' class='flakUp ui-droppable '>DropZone " + flakUpId + " </div>";
  $('#dropZones').prepend(flakUp);
})
```

2). I gave different ID=100 instead of 1.
  Because i saw another div with  id="1"

```
<div id="dropZones">
  <div class='flakUp' id="100">DropZone 1</div>
</div>
```

Full Code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="row well">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAddDropZone">Add dropZone</button>
</div>
<div id="dropZones">
  <div class='flakUp' id="100">DropZone 1</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="elementsDiv" id="1" style="width: 200px; height: 25px; background-color: #c2c2d6; cursor: move">Drag me 1</div>
<div class="elementsDiv" id="2" style="width: 150px; height: 35px; background-color: #c2c2d6; cursor: move">Drag me 2</div>
<div class="elementsDiv" id="3" style="width: 160px; height: 35px; background-color: #c2c2d6; cursor: move">Drag me 3</div>
```

**Script**

```
//Make elements Draggable
$('.elementsDiv').draggable({
  revert: 'invalid',
});
var flakUpId = $('#1').attr('id');

$('#btnAddDropZone').on('click', function() {
  flakUpId++;
  var flakUp = "<div id='12' class='flakUp ui-droppable'>DropZone " + flakUpId + " </div>";
  $('#dropZones').prepend(flakUp);
})

$('.flakUp, .flakDown').droppable({
  accept: '.elementsDiv',
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    var droppable = $(this);
    var draggable = ui.draggable;
    // Move draggable into droppable
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var relX = event.pageX - offset.left;
    var relY = event.pageY - offset.top;

    draggable.css({
      "left": ui.offset.left,
      "top": ui.offset.top,
      "position": "absolute"
    }).appendTo(droppable);
  },
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this did'nt change anything really.